# How to Show Tooltip on Telerik Grid in razor

Tags: razor

I am Trying to show tooltip on my telerik grid to show my column details on mouse over the row is it possible ?

Comment: Please, add more info as on what you've tried, and what is the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

Please see these pages:

http://jemmitch.wordpress.com/2012/05/05/tooltips-for-a-telerik-mvc-grid/

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/tooltip-in-telerik-grid.aspx

I hope they could be helpful.